# Post request returns empty string (python)

Tags: python-3.x, http-post

I need to get data from site. To get this data user have to enter post code first. After exploring the source code i got the following.

Response result (**that is what i need after all**)

```
{PostCodePK: 16666, PostCode: "7468", City: "MACQUARIE HEADS", State: "TAS", Country: "AUST",…}
1
:
{PostCodePK: 16667, PostCode: "7468", City: "STRAHAN", State: "TAS", Country: "AUST",…}
```

Request Data.

```
Request URL:http://www.lucasmill.com/Resources/ws-common.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:111.67.1.113:80
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:321
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 21 Feb 2017 20:19:26 GMT
Expires:Tue, 21 Feb 2017 20:19:26 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie:dnn_IsMobile=False; path=/; HttpOnly
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:18
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:.ASPXANONYMOUS=ptTlH_jC0gEkAAAAZTU4MTA5NTItZmNlZS00MzRjLThmYTgtMWZkYWNkOTEwZmY00; dnn_IsMobile=False; language=en-AU; __utmt=1; __utma=97280258.254723646.1487697408.1487697408.1487708346.2; __utmb=97280258.1.10.1487708346; __utmc=97280258; __utmz=97280258.1487697408.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
DNN-Service:true
DNN-Service-Method:GetTown
DNT:1
Host:www.lucasmill.com
Origin:http://www.lucasmill.com
Referer:http://www.lucasmill.com/Sawmilling-Contractors
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
{ 'param':'7468' }
```

Here is my python code.

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://www.lucasmill.com/Resources/ws-common.aspx',data={      'param':'7468' })
print(r.text)
```

but all i receive in response is an empty string.
Where am i wrong?

Comment: Your post request doesn't return anything even after I try it with `curl`, so your python code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Then how do i got the response results i need? Isn't this response data from site enough to get proper response data?

Comment: Looking.. So far I wasn't able to extract that exact response. I see it in the browser tho. Give me a few moments, I might figure something out.

Comment: Got it. Let me mod your code and I'll post the answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a few extra headers that particular application requires.
If you look at the request headers dump in the browser, you can see the following:

[image]

So, translated to python it will look like:

```
import json
import requests

headers = {
        'DNN-Service': 'true',
        'DNN-Service-Method': 'GetTown',
}

r = requests.post('http://www.lucasmill.com/Resources/ws-common.aspx',data=json.dumps({'param':7468}), headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

**Output**:

> [none][22:28:30] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests)$ python post.py
>   [{"PostCodePK":16666,"PostCode":"7468","City":"MACQUARIE
>   HEADS","State":"TAS","Country":"AUST","Latitude":"-42.2149353","Longitude":"145.1951436","CanGeocode":true},{"PostCodePK":16667,"PostCode":"7468","City":"STRAHAN","State":"TAS","Country":"AUST","Latitude":"-42.1534771","Longitude":"145.3281242","CanGeocode":true}]

Comment: How do you know what header to use and which one to left out? Looks like you used only half of them.

Comment: @BillyJhon removed some unnecessary ones too. Well, by trial and error. Basically the `DNN-*` headers drew my attention, since they are not standard. I assumed that the application on the other side of the fence expects those and I was right :)

Comment: Actually, only those 2 are needed, in fact.

Comment: Thanks alot) Will go dance with it further. Have a great night.

Comment: @BillyJhon You're welcome. Would appreciate if you accept the answer too :)

Comment: one final question.  { 'param':'MACQUARIE HEADS, TAS, 7468, 16666' } here i need to pass multiple parameters. it works fine when i use hardcoded values. But as soon as i substitute them with variable - it returns empty string. The question is how can i pass params as variables. I tried list and tuple. no avil. like { 'param':[city, state, postCode, postCodePk]}

Comment: What's in the variable? :)

Comment: values from dictionary i got from first request. (this site uses 3 consequtive requests to get to final data)                                                                                                 city = r.json()[0]["City"]
    state = r.json()[0]["State"]
    postCode = r.json()[0]["PostCode"]
    postCodePk = r.json()[0]["PostCodePK"]

Comment: Ah, you're passing a list, that's not gonna work. `'param': '{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(city, state, postCode, postCodePk)` should work there